# connect android device wirelessly through command line

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line

This might be a dumb question, but I'm trying to connect a tablet so I can make an app in Android Studio. All the guides I see (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless) tells me to go to the command line and use adb commands. Where do I have to navigate to to use that command?

I've gone to C:/Users/*myusername*/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/tools

from there I've tried navigating to other directories and try to use the adb command but it won't let me. I don't know which directory I have to navigate to to use the adb commands, but I believe it's somewhere around where I'm looking, but I can't exactly find it.

Comment: Try looking in `/Android/sdk/platform-tools`, there should be an `adb.exe` there.

Comment: God I'm blind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

from there right click and open command window here and then continue as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/3838663

Comment: Thanks, apparently I must be blind.

Comment: @JoshSuttenberg No problem, I will appreciate if you will upvote me :)

Comment: I did, but I don't have 15 rep yet so it won't show. I just joined the site.